# MS Access: Using the value of the field in a given column of the selected row of a ListBox as criterion in a query

Tags: sql, forms, ms-access

On a form "Search Invoices By Customer ID 2" I have a ListBox control "invoiceList" showing a set of records from the table "InvoiceFirsts".

I want to get a the contents of a column from the selected row in the ListBox.

I have a test text box "Text6" on the same form whose control source is "=[invoiceList].Column" , and the value I want is there.

I want to use this same value as a criterion to select a single record in a query "one invoice". I set the criteria for the field INVOICE_NO in the table InvoiceFirsts to

=[Forms]![Search Invoices By Customer ID 2]![invoiceList].Column

Running the query returns a dialog "Undefined function '[Forms]![Search Invoices By Customer ID 2]![invoiceList].[Column]' in expression.

The SQL view shows me:

SELECT InvoiceFirsts.INVOICE_NO
FROM InvoiceFirsts
WHERE (((InvoiceFirsts.INVOICE_NO)=[Forms]![Search Invoices By Customer ID 2]![invoiceList].Column));

Why can't I use the same syntax for the query as I do for the text box, or alternatively, how should I go about selecting by the contents of a field in the selected row of a ListBox?

Comment: As I recall column in comboBoxes and listBoxes is a 0 based Array so I'm surprised you are getting anything in the textbox.  so try adjusting all your code with invoiceList.Column(appropriateColumnNumber)

Comment: Just to add, I don't think you can reference a property such as `.Column(x)` in a query. If you are putting the value of the ListBox column you want to reference in to another textbox on your form (sounds like you're doing this for "Text6") you can refer to that textbox in your query instead of the ListBox directly.

Comment: This is odd. Something happened in the copy/paste to Stackoverflow. The real source of Text 6 is "=[invoiceList].Column(1)" , and the query is "=[Forms]![Search Invoices By Customer ID 2]![invoiceList].Column(1)". Something ate all of my (1)s in the original post.

Comment: @MattHall This works, thanks - I was hoping to just use the text box for testing, but my requirements are pretty loose and I can manage this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reference a function in your SQL so you can create a public function in a module to get the invoice number and return it to the SQL:

```
Public Function fInvoice() As Variant
  fInvoice = [Forms]![Search Invoices By Customer ID 2]![invoiceList].Column(1)
End Function
```

Change your SQL:

```
SELECT InvoiceFirsts.INVOICE_NO FROM InvoiceFirsts WHERE InvoiceFirsts.INVOICE_NO=fInvoice();
```

This will only work if your form is still open. The query cannot be run by itself.

Comment: Thanks for this. It makes perfect sense (though why some control properties can be used in queries and some cannot doesn't to me). I

'm rusty enough in VBA and surprised enough by how difficult it is for me to follow the ways VBA, Macros, forms reports and queries interact in Access to just dodge and use the text box.